How do i access a deployed service's exposed port
I have a simple spring boot service which performs CRUD Operations using MySQL. I dockerized my service and pulled an image of mysql and got the images to run on the same network and work.
The problem is that i am unable to access the service using the default exposed port (defined as 7070).
Here are my spring datasource properties defined in application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/test
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=image
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#----ADDITIONAL PROPERTIES-----#
server.port = 7070
server.servlet.context-path=/jpatest
server.servlet.session.timeout=15m

Here is how i pulled and ran the mysql image:
$ docker network create image

$ docker run --name mysql --network image -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<pwd> -d mysql:8.3.0

$ docker run -it --network image --rm mysql mysql -hmysql -uroot -p<pwd> 

This is my DOCKERFILE:
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-focal as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle

COPY build.gradle settings.gradle ./
COPY src src

RUN ./gradlew clean build

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/*.jar ./

EXPOSE 7070

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "jpatest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

This is the docker start command: docker run -it --network image --publish 7070 <image_name>
Here are the spring startup logs:

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.2)

2024-07-01T11:07:30.356Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.test.jpatest.JpatestApplication      : Starting JpatestApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.2 with PID 1 (/app/jpatest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /app)
2024-07-01T11:07:30.369Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.test.jpatest.JpatestApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-07-01T11:07:32.646Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-07-01T11:07:32.652Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-01T11:07:32.723Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.test.jpatest.repo.TXBooking_MasterRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2024-07-01T11:07:32.728Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.test.jpatest.repo.UserRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2024-07-01T11:07:32.730Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 64 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2024-07-01T11:07:32.745Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-07-01T11:07:32.747Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-07-01T11:07:32.985Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 229 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-07-01T11:07:34.491Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 7070 (http)
2024-07-01T11:07:34.514Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-01T11:07:34.517Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-07-01T11:07:34.616Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/jpatest]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-01T11:07:34.620Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4065 ms
2024-07-01T11:07:35.404Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-07-01T11:07:35.536Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.1.Final
2024-07-01T11:07:35.610Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-07-01T11:07:36.180Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-07-01T11:07:36.244Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-07-01T11:07:37.071Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2d8c729f
2024-07-01T11:07:37.077Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-07-01T11:07:39.256Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-07-01T11:07:39.772Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-07-01T11:07:40.413Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : JSqlParser is in classpath; If applicable, JSqlParser will be used
2024-07-01T11:07:40.414Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.QueryEnhancerFactory     : Hibernate is in classpath; If applicable, HQL parser will be used.
2024-07-01T11:07:41.374Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-07-01T11:07:42.851Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 14 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-07-01T11:07:43.022Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 7070 (http) with context path '/jpatest'
2024-07-01T11:07:43.055Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.test.jpatest.JpatestApplication      : Started JpatestApplication in 14.028 seconds (process running for 15.228)

But when i access the service using the port I defined (7070), it does not find the page. But the service runs perfectly fine when I use the defined HostPort in the image inspect. Below is a snippet of my service image config.
"Ports": {
                "7070/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "32770"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "32770"
                    }
                ]
            },


The service works when i use http://0.0.0.0:32770/jpatest or http://localhost:32770/jpatest
I have to inspect the container every time to get the defined HostPort as it keeps changing every time i stop and start the service.
Is there any solution to this?
The service works when i use http://0.0.0.0:32770/jpatest or http://localhost:32770/jpatest
I have to inspect the container every time to get the defined HostPort as it keeps changing every time i stop and start the service.
I am expecting my service to be accessible on the port i exposed (7070) but it is not.
Is there any solution to this?

You need to publish the port on the service container and specify which host port you want it published to. Right now you publish it but you don't specify a host port, so Docker chooses one for you. Port 32770 in your example.
To map port 7070 to a specific host port, you use -p <port>:7070 or --publish <port>:7070 on the docker run command.
So, to publish the container port to host port 7070, you'd use
docker run -it --network image --publish 7070:7070 <image_name>

Then your service will be available on port 7070 on the host.

Thank you Hans. This worked for me. Seems like I totally forgot to specify which port to publish the 7070 port to.
adding the -p 7070:7070 argument did the trick.
